# Howt to convert a stock market HTML page for data analysis in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup, stockquotes

I have been analysing the stock market for my work and I normally manually input the data into Excel for analysis.  Recently I have been touching on using Python for data analysis and web scraping.  I wish to extract the data from the Hong Kong Exchange website.

For example, https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsif200819.htm, I wish to extract the data of the HK future contracts.  It can be clearly seen that there is a table contain the data I want, but I found that the java script does not contain any table for the extract.  Instead it is all text format.

I have captured the screen to indicate the data that I want to capture for my analysis.  It can be useful if the whole table can be converted into data frame for easier analysis.
[Data to be captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm82y.jpg)

I have tried to use the beautifulsoup package from python to extract data but in vain.

Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this - even without using any code.

Below are the details from this website: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/

The imports:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
Next we will use requests.get to retrieve the web page with our data, parse it using the html module, and save the results in tree:

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

(We need to use page.content rather than page.text because html.fromstring implicitly expects bytes as input.)

tree now contains the whole HTML file in a nice tree structure which we can go over two different ways: XPath and CSSSelect. In this example, we will focus on the former.

XPath is a way of locating information in structured documents such as HTML or XML documents. A good introduction to XPath is on W3Schools .

There are also various tools for obtaining the XPath of elements such as FireBug for Firefox or the Chrome Inspector. If you’re using Chrome, you can right click an element, choose ‘Inspect element’, highlight the code, right click again, and choose ‘Copy XPath’.

After a quick analysis, we see that in our page the data is contained in two elements – one is a div with title ‘buyer-name’ and the other is a span with class ‘item-price’:

```
<div title="buyer-name">Carson Busses</div>
<span class="item-price">$29.95</span>
Knowing this we can create the correct XPath query and use the lxml xpath function like this:

#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')
Let’s see what we got exactly:

print 'Buyers: ', buyers
print 'Prices: ', prices
Buyers:  ['Carson Busses', 'Earl E. Byrd', 'Patty Cakes',
'Derri Anne Connecticut', 'Moe Dess', 'Leda Doggslife', 'Dan Druff',
'Al Fresco', 'Ido Hoe', 'Howie Kisses', 'Len Lease', 'Phil Meup',
'Ira Pent', 'Ben D. Rules', 'Ave Sectomy', 'Gary Shattire',
'Bobbi Soks', 'Sheila Takya', 'Rose Tattoo', 'Moe Tell']

Prices:  ['$29.95', '$8.37', '$15.26', '$19.25', '$19.25',
'$13.99', '$31.57', '$8.49', '$14.47', '$15.86', '$11.11',
'$15.98', '$16.27', '$7.50', '$50.85', '$14.26', '$5.68',
'$15.00', '$114.07', '$10.09']
```

This will successfully scraped all the data we wanted from a web page using lxml and Requests. We have it stored in memory as two lists. Now we can do all sorts of cool stuff with it: we can analyze it using Python or we can save it to a file and share it with the world.

Some more cool ideas to think about are modifying this script to iterate through the rest of the pages of this example dataset, or rewriting this application to use threads for improved speed.